# pssh freezes only inside shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to run a `pssh` command inside a shell script, but the script freezes and there are no connections made, as verified in a `ps -ef` command. Also, because there is only one host in the hosts file I am using.

At this point, Control-C fails to kill the script, and it will not timeout. Only a `kill` command works.

If I run the same command on the command-line, there is no issue. Also, a `pscp` command in the same script causes no issues, so it seems that the required libraries are being loaded.

```
$ cat /home/myusername/tmp/hosts
mysinglehostname
```

Here is the script being run:

```
$ cat /home/myusername/bin/testpssh
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
$HOME/path/to/python-virtualenv/bin/pscp -h "/home/myusername/tmp/hosts" "/tmp/garbage" "/tmp/garbage"
$HOME/path/to/python-virtualenv/bin/pssh -h "/home/myusername/tmp/hosts" -l myusername -p 512 -t 3 -o "out" -O GSSAPIAuthentication=no -i "whoami"
```

Here is what happens when I run the script:

```
$ /home/myusername/bin/testpssh &
[1] 18553
$ [1] 14:51:12 [SUCCESS] mysinglehostname 22    
$ ps -ef | grep pssh
myusername  18580 18553 0 14:33 pts/16   00:00:00 /home/myusername/path/to/python-virtualenv/bin/python /home/myusername/path/to/python-virtualenv/bin/pssh -h /home/myusername/tmp/hosts -l myusername -p 512 -t 3 -o out -O GSSAPIAuthentication=no -i whoami

$ ## The script above is hanging after completing the pscp, before pssh completes.\
> But if I copy and paste the process line, it works fine as shown here:

$ /home/myusername/path/to/python-virtualenv/bin/python \
> /home/myusername/path/to/python-virtualenv/bin/pssh \
> -h /home/myusername/tmp/hosts -l myusername \
> -p 512 -t 3 -o out -O GSSAPIAuthentication=no -i whoami
[1] 14:59:03 [SUCCESS] mysinglehostname 22
myusername
$
```

The first [SUCCESS] above is for the `pscp` action, and no subsequent [SUCCESS] comes from the `pssh` command, unless it is performed explicitly on the command-line.

Why will the pssh command not work inside the bash shell script?

The script works fine if I use `ksh` instead of `bash` (and remove the line to `source ~/.bashrc`) in the shebang line.

I am on RedHat 6.4, using python 2.6.6

Comment: hm, the shell script should be inheriting the virtual environment, but just to make sure, can you `source $HOME/path/to/python-virtualenv/bin/activate` inside the `testpssh` script? Probably not this, just wanting to remove a line of inquiry

Comment: I wasn't in the virtual environment when running the script, which is why I put the full path to python. I found the issue though, the pssh script has a place where it runs stdin=sys.stdin.read(). This hangs unless the shell script is started in interactive mode. I.e. running #!/bin/bash -i as the shebang.

Comment: The script you posted in the question worked for me (with my own hostname, of course), so I'm not sure what the difference is. Out of interest, why are you not activating the virtual environment?

Comment: strange it works for you. What python version are you using? it works for me with ksh with single host, but with large host list I need the -i flag. I didnt activate the environment because I didn't think it would make a difference in this case. The python path is hardcoded in the shebang of pssh after installation into virtualenv. I'm not using PYTHONPATH variable, and I'm not aware of any other major changes that activating virtualenv would cause.

Comment: Python 2.7.11, since I tried 3.5 and pssh had errors installing. The example you posted worked for me with a single host